# Unit test with sinon fake does not resolve promise

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, shelljs

I'm learning nodejs and wrote this wrapper for a shelljs function, which in practice seems to work as intended.

```
/**
 * Wrapper for Shelljs.exec to always return a promise
 *
 * @param  {String} cmd - bash-compliant command string
 * @param  {String} path - working directory of the process
 * @param {Object} _shell - alternative exec function for testing.
 * @returns {String}
 * @throws {TypeError}
 */
function shellExec(cmd, path, _shell = shelljs){
    if( typeof _shell.exec !== "function") throw new TypeError('_shell.exec must be a function');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let options =  { cwd: path, silent: true, asyc: true }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        return _shell.exec(cmd, options, (code, stdout, stderr) => {
            // shelljs.exec does not always return a code
            if(stderr) {
                return reject(stderr);
            }
            return resolve(stdout);
        });
    });
}
```

However when I attempt to unit test it, the function times out. I have read the mochajs docs about async code, [promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) or [async/await](https://mochajs.org/#using-async--await) in tests. I want to use a [sinon fake that returns a promise](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.4/fakes/) which I know works. Mocha tells me the error is that the function is not returning a promise via the error `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves`. I imagine I have constructed the fake improperly but I cannot see how else I should have done this.

```
const { expect, use } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
const utils = require('../utility/exec');

use(sinonChai);

it('sinon fake should resolve', async () =>{
    const fake = sinon.fake.resolves('resolved');

    const result = await fake();
    expect(result).to.equal('resolved');
});
describe('Utility Functions', () =>{
    describe('shellExec', () =>{
        it('should accept an alternate execute function', async () =>{
            const fakeShell = { exec: sinon.fake.resolves('pass') };
            const result = await utils.shellExec('pwd', 'xyz', fakeShell);
            expect(result).to.equal('pass');
            expect(fakeShell.exec).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I found both the answers from Peter and Dat Tran were both quite helpful, but Peter's was more on point about the actual test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function is a little complex but nothing sinon can't handle with stubs.  See https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/ for more info but what you should use is `callsArgOnWith` before the function.

Instead of setting `exec` to return a promise you need to set it as a stub.  This way you can call the callback using the `callsArgOnWith` function when it is encountered.

I've changed your test so it now passes by changing the fake `exec` function to return a stub `const fakeShell = { exec: sinon.stub() };` and adding the line `fakeShell.exec.callsArgOnWith(2, null, null, 'pass', null)` before running your function

```
const { expect, use } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
const utils = require('./main');


use(sinonChai);

it('sinon fake should resolve', async () =>{
    const fake = sinon.fake.resolves('resolved');

    const result = await fake();
    expect(result).to.equal('resolved');
});
describe('Utility Functions', () =>{
    describe('shellExec', () =>{
        it('should accept an alternate execute function', async () =>{
            const fakeShell = { exec: sinon.stub() };
            fakeShell.exec.callsArgOnWith(2, null, null, 'pass', null)
            const result = await utils.shellExec('pwd', 'xyz', fakeShell);            
            expect(result).to.equal('pass');
            expect(fakeShell.exec).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I read the docs at link you provided but clear as mud to me. Could you explain the parameters in `callsArgOnWith(2, null, null, 'pass', null)`?

Comment: `stub.callsArgOnWith(index, context, arg1, arg2, ...);`
Index - which argument of the exec function the callback. 0 indexed, context - any scope you want to pass through, then the rest are the arguments you pass to the callback

Answer (score 1):

your `_shell.exec` is just a callback function, It's not a Promise. That's why when you fake shell.exec to be a promise, your `resolve` will never been called. I think you need to fake your fakeShell to something like this:

```
const fakeShell = { 
   exec: (cmd, options, cb) => {
      cb(true, 'pass', null);
   }
};
```

Comment: You are saying that I don't need to use any sinon objects here, I just pass the new fakeShell in and test the result?  I didn't see that `_shell` was a callback, though when I use the function it responds to `.then`/`.catch`.

Comment: shell.exec is a call back function. when It finish, it use the resolve from The outer promise to resolve it. That's the meaning of the function. Wrap a callback into  a promise.

Comment: `_shell.exec(cmd, options, (code, stdout, stderr) => {` => `cmd` is the 1st parameter, `options` is the 2nd, `(code, stdout, stderr) => {}` is the 3rd parameter, It's actually the callback function which is called after the _shell.exec is finished.

Comment: I see now that I don't need shelljs at all in this instance as utilities `promisfy()` method of `exec` achieves the same effect.  The parameters are the same!